# How to setup a phpStorm javascript debug session over MVC Framework projects?

Tags: php, debugging, yii, phpstorm

System:
**MAC OS X ; MAMP PRO ; phpStorm 7.1.1**

We wish to start using *live edit*. However, if we right click on a given file and we try to make a javascript “debug” we get a 404 error, because it doesn’t take into consideration the *framework root configurations* for that purpose.

We get redirected to an inexistent url:

> http://site.dev/app/views/home/index.php

Instead of:

> http://site.dev/home/index/

or just

> http://site.dev/home/

**Has any of you had properly setup a *javascript debug session* in order to work with php frameworks?** (in this case we are talking about Yii, but an example with others may be useful).

Please advice.

Comment: Create Run/Debug Configuration **manually** -- put correct opening URL (in URL field) and specify mappings if required (local file vs remote URL). The problem with all of this *could be* the fact that you most likely generate all that in PHP as opposed to separate js files.

Comment: So if I have an application with 400 view pages, I have to setup, for each of those pages, a manual URL redirection? o.O - I may pass most of the js to a proper js folder containing the scripts. If that couldn't be the case, I will debug using other methods.

Comment: @LazyOne Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.